# PHP MySQL Cursors? or Query without fetching

Tags: php, python, mysql

I'm running some queries that takes 0,0053 secs on run but about 12secs on fetching... That causes timeouts in PHP when fetching about 100,000 rows.

I'm wondering if there's a way to speed up the fetching using a cursor or something, like in Python in where you can go trhough a loop without fetching every row... Because everything is breaking with the timeouts in PHP

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: What about raising the timeouts when you already know that your timeout setting will be violated? I mean timeouts are there to protect you, not to annmoy you.

Comment: The real question is why would you need to fetch that many rows ? And you can use the LIMIT directive in your queries to only select a particular range of rows.

Comment: Raising the timeouts isn't an option because if I need to parse 300,000 rows isn't the same time that I need for 100,000.

I need that many rows because I'm sending messages to RabbitMQ that will be processed later on Python or other languages. But this message needs to be sent from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  `SELECT COUNT(*)...` to see whether it is 100K or 300K or whatever.  Plug that into an empirical formula (like `$seconds = 10 + $count / 2000`) and plug that into `set_time_limit($seconds)`.  (This assumes you don't timeout doing the `COUNT(*)`!)

Plan B:  "Chunk" the data so you are not trying to fetch it all at once.  (Keep in mind that PHP has a default memory limit that you might be threatening to exceed.)  Chunking should not use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, instead "remember where it left off"; otherwise it will get slower and slower and eventually time out.  More details on chunking are in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig .